# Will paginate rails limit num of pages to max 10?

Tags: ruby, will-paginate

I am using will paginate for pagination. I have total 11 pages currently. At footer it shows all the 11 pages no matter on what page the user is. How can I display max 10 pages at footer. So if user comes on page no 5 it will show 5 pages before and after. Not all at once.

Comment: I prefer to use kaminari

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `inner_window` and `outer_window` [options](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/2-3-stable/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb#L51-L52) to control how many page links are displayed. If you only want to show 5 pages on either side of the current page, your view would look like:

```
<%= will_paginate @objects, inner_window: 5, outer_window: 0 %>
```

Though because your current page is also included, you'll have to show an odd number (1 + N * 2), so I hope you're alright with 9 or 11.

If you really want to get into it, you'll notice there's also a [renderer option](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/2-3-stable/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb#L67) that lets you pass a custom link rendering class. The renderer instance needs to response to `prepare` and `to_html` like the [default renderer](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/2-3-stable/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb#L246) does.